# Buscar un objeto con campo null en neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graphql

Estoy trabajando con Neo4j, tengo nodos que representan eventos que pasan en la vida de los usuarios, como cumpleaños, exámenes, etc., algunos de estos eventos tienen fecha de vencimiento y otros no, necesito mostrar los eventos que la fecha de vencimiento sea mayor que la fecha actual o que no tenga fecha de vencimiento, o sea, que sea `null`, segun tengo entendido en Neo4j no se pueden definir Propiedades con valor `null`, en tal caso es un nodo que no tiene dicha propiedad, pero entonces ¿cómo puedo construir la consulta que necesito?, o sea, sería algo así: `match (e:Event) where e.dueAt<132456790 or e.dueAt=null return e`, pero esta consulta es incorrecta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque el server de Neo4j no almacena las Propiedades con valores `null`, sí se puede filtar por ellos, la consulta quedaría así:
`match (e:Event) where e.dueAt<132456790 or e.dueAt IS NULL return e`